# Why java ForkJoinPool default constructor limit parallelism parameter

Tags: java, constructor, forkjoinpool

This is ForkJoinPool default constructor.

```
public ForkJoinPool() {
    this(Math.min(MAX_CAP, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()),
         defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, false);
}
```

And this is all argument constructor.

```
public ForkJoinPool(int parallelism,
                    ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory,
                    UncaughtExceptionHandler handler,
                    boolean asyncMode)
```

MAX_CAP is

```
static final int MAX_CAP      = 0x7fff;        // max #workers - 1
```

Why limit MAX_CAP and 0x7fff has special meanning?

Comment: `0x7fff` is not `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7fffffff`.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood. Thank you!

Comment: I changed question.